# UWP when many GirdViews(one row enabled) nested in ListView, ListView's performance is very bad

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I'm designing a page like NetFlix home page. It has many(20+) `GirdView`s(one row enabled) nested in an outer `ListView`. All items are uncertained, so they must be generated at run time.
So I designed like belows:

### Xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstLevelListViewItemTemplate" x:DataType="model:CategoriesItem">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CategoryName}" FontSize="28"/>

                <GridView
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Height="200"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind categories, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:CategoryItem">
                            <controls:ImageEx IsCacheEnabled="True" Width="250" Source="{x:Bind cover_image_url}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--<ScrollViewer>-->
        <ListView x:Name="list"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FirstLevelListViewItemTemplate}">
    <!--Disable ListView UI virtualization-->
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
```

### Model file:

```
public class CategoriesItem
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryItem> categories { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryItem
{
    public string cover_image_url { get; set; }
}
```

### .cs file

used to load data from local:

```
list.ItemsSource = await GetData();
```

So

### Scene 1:

Run app with `ListView`'s UI virtualization enabled, bind process is very quick and memory is about 300MB. Then use mouse to scrolling up/down ListView quickly, the `ListView` scrolls up and down very slow, and show data very slow after a screen blank.
[image]

### Scene 2:

Run app with `ListView`'s UI virtualization disabled, this time  the bind process takes a very long time, and the memory may rise to 1GB. But scrolling up/down ListView quickly, it's all OK.

### My needs:

- Scrolling up/down ListView quickly performs fast.
- Bind process quick and memory low.

### How to fix?

How to fix this, many thanks.
[image]

Comment: ScrollViewer can disable ListView's data visualization.

Comment: The same design mode on ios and android performs excellent, fast speed and low memory, scroll up/down ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the live visual tree shows all the ListViewItems, because I will use all the ListViewItems to do some extra things.

For explain this behavior,we could refer  [**UI virtualization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization), UI virtualization is the most important improvement you can make.

> This means that UI elements representing the items are created on demand. For an items control bound to a 1000-item collection, it would be a waste of resources to create the UI for all the items at the same time, because they can't all be displayed at the same time. ListView and GridView (and other standard ItemsControl-derived controls) perform UI virtualization for you. When items are close to being scrolled into view (a few pages away), the framework generates the UI for the items and caches them. When it's unlikely that the items will be shown again, the framework re-claims the memory.

You could turn it off with change  `ItemsPanelTemplate` as `StackPanel`

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />

        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

> Bind process quick and memory low.

You could make a the data virtualization that cut the json data into slices, then use ListView [`LoadMoreItemsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.loadmoreitemsasync#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListViewBase_LoadMoreItemsAsync) to load more.

Comment: Maybe you described above is a workaround, but situations like ListView/GridView in ListView is still common, the performance in uwp is not satisfactory comparing to android/ios.

Comment: emm,  If you could post this on User Voice that  would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, a user voice has been created, see https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/38013196-gridview-listview-nested-in-listview-performsreall

Comment: Finally, I cut the json file, and load them when scroll to footer. Thx.